# Site definition inherit/display parent global navigation

Tags: site-definition

When creating a Site Definition in Visual Studio, how do I make sure that the new site created from this definition will display the same global navigation as the parent web in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can control this with the publishing navigation feature. Take a look at the **InheritGlobalNavigation** key.

```
<WebFeatures>
 ...
 <Feature ID="541F5F57-C847-4e16-B59A-B31E90E6F9EA">
      <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Property Key="InheritGlobalNavigation" Value="true"/>
      <Property Key="ShowSiblings" Value="true"/>
      <Property Key="IncludeSubSites" Value="true"/>
      </Properties>
 </Feature>
 ...
```

Comment: is this placed in the onet.xml? and is the id the feature GUID?

Comment: @NicholasKing Yes and Yes.